# How do I sort input with a variable number of fields by the second-to-last field?

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, awk, scripting

<sup>Editor's note: The original title of the question mentioned *tabs* as the field separators.</sup>

In a text such as

```
500 east 23rd avenue Toronto 2 890 400000 1 
900 west yellovillage blvd Mississauga 3 800 600090 3
```

how would you sort in ascending order of the second to last column?

<sup>Editor's note: The OP later provided another sample input line, `500 Jackson Blvd Toronto 3 700 40000 2`, which contains only *8* whitespace-separated input fields (compared to the *9* above), revealing the need to deal with a *variable* number of fields in the input.</sup>

Comment: `info sort` or `man sort`.

Comment: Short answer `sort -n -k 8 <path/to/file.txt` to sort numerically by the 8th key (field) in each line.

Comment: Where are the tabs? Is the number of fields constant as in the example, or can you have items such as '899 edmonton street montreal 9 499 333222 9' (pulling names and numbers out of thin air semi-randomly). That doesn't have a north/south/east/west designator, so it ends up with 8 fields instead of 9. If the structure does not have a fixed number of fields, you have to work a lot harder than if it does. In fact, you may need to rework the data so that the fields can be split for easier processing with the sort command, separating the numbers and city from the street address and each other.

Comment: 500 Jackson Blvd     Toronto   3   700 40000 2  
900 yellowvillage avenue road  Mississauga 3 800 600090 3.                  555 calway road  Toronto  2 840 500000  4
and in this case the second to the last column signifies kilometres but there are they have different column numbers in their respective lines so how do you sort it in ascending order of the second to last column. thats my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: There are several, potentially separate questions:

**Update**: Question **C** was the relevant one.

- **Question A:** As implied by the question's title *only*: how can you use the tab character (`\t`) as the field separator?
- **Question B:** How can you sort input by the second-to-last field, without knowing that field's specific index up front, given a *fixed* number of fields?
- **Question C:** How can you sort input by the second-to-last field, without knowing that field's respective index up front, given a *variable* number of fields?

---

**Answer to question A:**

[`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html)'s `-t` option allows you to specify a field separator.
By default, `sort` uses any run of line-interior whitespace as the separator.

Assuming Bash, Ksh, or Zsh, you can use an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`) to specify a single tab as the field separator (`$'\t'`):

```
sort -t $'\t' -n -k8,8 file # -n sorts numerically; omit for lexical sorting
```

---

**Answer to question B:**

Note: This assumes that all input lines have the *same* number of fields, and that input comes from file `file`:

```
 # Determine the index of the next-to-last column, based on the first
 # line, using Awk:
 nextToLastColNdx=$(head -n 1 file | awk -F '\t' '{ print NF - 1 }')

 # Sort numerically by the next-to-last column (omit -n to sort lexically):
 sort -t $'\t' -n -k$nextToLastColNdx,$nextToLastColNdx file
```

Note: To sort by a *single* field, always specify it as the *end* field too (e.g., `-k8,8`), as above, because `sort`, given only a *start* field index (e.g., `-k8`), sorts from the specified field *through the remainder of the line*.

---

**Answer to question C:**

Note: This assumes that input lines may have a *variable* number of fields, and that on each line it is *that line's* second-to-last field that should act as the sort field; input comes from file `file`:

```
awk '{ printf "%s\t%s\n", $(NF-1), $0 }' file |
  sort -n -k1,1 | # omit -n to perform lexical sorting
    cut -f2-
```

- The `awk` command extracts each line's second-to-last field and *prepends* it to the input line on output, separated by a tab.
- The result is sorted by the first field (i.e., each input line's second-to-last field).
- Finally, the artificially prepended sort field is removed again, using `cut`.

Comment: 500 east 23rd avenue Toronto 2 890 400000 1 
900 west yellovillage blvd street Mississauga 3 800 600090 3.     in this case how do you sort the second to the last because it no more the 8th column on both lines

Comment: thanks. this really helped me a lot, however, what does this particular phrase  "%s\t%s\n" mean because i don't seem to see it whenever i practise or look for help

Comment: @biggie: `"%s\t%s\n"` is a format string for Awk's `printf` function, which tells it how to format its arguments: `%s` represents the first argument and prints it as-is (as a string), followed by `\t` - a tab character -, followed by the second argument as-is (`%s` again), terminated with `\n`, a newline char. In effect, the second-to-last field value (`$(NF-1)`; `NF` represents the number of fields on the line) is printed first, followed by a tab, followed by the input line as-is (`$0`).

Comment: ok then what if the user was to type in an input in a script. e.g Mississauga from the above example and we want awk to filter it according to the variable of the $user_input and sort it by the second to the last column?

Comment: @biggie: I'll give a quick answer here, but - in order to make your question and the answers useful to others too, which is what this site is about -  please (a) define your question more precisely next time and (b) don't expand the scope of the question later.

`awk -v user_input="$user_input" '$0 ~ user_input { … ` (rest as above); this matches only lines that contain the value of `$user_input`, _anywhere_ on the line.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at "man sort".

You will see how to specify a field separator and how to specify the field index that should be used as a key for sorting.

Comment: That is not a good answer, I'm afraid.  You should at least suggest how you would handle the last-but-one field using `sort` options.  You might also mention how to exploit tab delimiters, while also asking where they are in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort -k 2`

For example :

```
echo -e '000 west \n500 east\n500 east\n900 west' | sort -k 2
```

The result is :

```
500 east
500 east
900 west
000 west
```

You can find more informations in the man page of sort. Take a look a the end of the man page. Just before author you have some interesting informations :)

Bye

Comment: Wouldn't `-k 8` be closer?